# PHP Redirect on Cookie Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

Hi I want all my new / 1st users to my site to get redirected to a different page.

Its a wordpress page and in the index.php file I have this code right on top

```
<?php
if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes") { 
setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+20000);  
header("Location: http://howtobuygoldoffshore.com/sitemap"); 
exit;
}
?>
```

Now the issue is when I clear all cache and cookies from my browser and access this page it only goes to howtobuygoldoffshore.com instead of going to howtobuygoldoffshore.com/sitemap.

But now if I access it with a www.howtobuygoldoffshore.com then it goes to the correct landing page.(the www. is making some different I suppose)

What could be the issue? Is the code correct which I am writing and inserting in the index.php file or is there some issue with the re direction?

Comment: You know this will confuse users? Let's say google send me to a page, then you redirect me to a different page where that information is not present. A pop up box would be better. Also a real popup when I want to leave? Feels quite like a spam site with features like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cookie isn't for all the subdomains on your site.

[setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )

See the parameter $domain. Try to save your cookie as $domain = `howtobuygoldoffshore.com` instead:

```
setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+20000, '/', 'howtobuygoldoffshore.com');
```

This will make your cookie work on both `http://howtobuygoldoffshore.com` and `http://www.howtobuygoldoffshore.com`.

Comment: Thanks. But I did not understand where to make the changes in my current code. Can you please help with that. Ie:<?php
if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes") { 
setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+20000);  
header("Location: http://howtobuygoldoffshore.com/sitemap"); 
exit;
}
?> where do Make the changes $domain and the set cookie parameter?

Comment: Replace setcookie() row with above one in my answer.

Comment: I did that and now my code happens to be this : <?php
if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes") { 
setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+20000, '/', '.howtobuygoldoffshore.com');  
header("Location: http://howtobuygoldoffshore.com/sitemap"); 
exit;
}
?> Still it does not seem to redirect without the 'www' I still have to put www before it redirects it to the correct page

Comment: Try removing the dot (`.`). In the $domain. For some reason I though it was needed, but it aint.

Comment: I did that too - if ($_COOKIE['iwashere'] != "yes") { 
setcookie("iwashere", "yes", time()+20000, '/', 'howtobuygoldoffshore.com');  
header("Location: http://www.howtobuygoldoffshore.com/sitemap"); 
exit; still doesnt seem to work for some reason

Comment: Also my wordpress files are not in the root folder. Its in a sub folder inside public_html so does that make any changes to the above redirect code?

Comment: The `'/'` isn't for the ftp folder, but for the users adress in the browser. I will get back to you if I find why this isn't working for you. I suggest you to try to `print_r($_COOKIES)`. Troubleshooting will get you far.

Comment: Works now. There was some problem with my .htaccess file which was preventing that from happening